# List out patron visit day and summarize their lag days in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I would like to ask how to transform the below data set into the two outcome tables which

1. have unique name as the row and list the trip 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on of each person and have the avg trip n grand total at last column n row.
2. The second table I want to know the lag days between trips and avg. lag day of each person as the last column. Lag is the day between trips.

## Dataset

```r
name <- c('Mary', 'Sue', 'Peter', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'John', 'Sue', 'Peter',
          'Peter', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Mary', 'Mary')
date <- c('01/04/2018', '03/02/2017', '01/01/2019', '24/04/2017', 
          '02/03/2019', '31/05/2019', '08/09/2019', '17/12/2019', 
          '02/08/2017', '10/11/2017', '30/12/2017', '18/02/2018', 
          '18/02/2018', '18/10/2019')
data <- data.frame(name, date)
```

The desired results:

```
Result 1

Name  Trip 1        Trip2     Total trips
Mary  dd/mm/yyyy   dd/mm/yyyy   2
John  dd/mm/yyyy.   N/A         1
Total Trip  2        1          3

Result 2
Name Lag1 Lag2 Avg.Lag
Mary  3    4    3.5
John  5    1     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Result 1 can be achieved by arranging the data by date (first convert to date format) and doing a group_by() per person to calculate the rank and count of the trips. These can then by pivoted into columns using `pivot_wider()` from the tidyr package (the `paste0()` lines are to ensure readable column names).

For result 2 the difference in days needs to be calculated between trips using `difftime()`, which will give an NA for the first trip. The rest of the procedure is similar to result 1, but some columns have to be removed before the pivot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

name <- c('Mary','Sue','Peter','Mary','Mary','John','Sue','Peter','Peter','John',
          'John','John','Mary','Mary')
date <- c('01/04/2018','03/02/2017','01/01/2019','24/04/2017',
          '02/03/2019','31/05/2019','08/09/2019','17/12/2019',
          '02/08/2017','10/11/2017','30/12/2017','18/02/2018',
          '18/02/2018','18/10/2019')

data <- data.frame(name,date, stringsAsFactors = F)

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')) %>% 
  arrange(name, date) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(trip_nr = rank(date),
         total_trips = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() 

result1 <- data %>% 
  mutate(trip_nr = paste0('Trip_', trip_nr)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = trip_nr, values_from = date)

result2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(lag = difftime(date, lag(date), units = 'days'),
         lag_avg = mean(lag, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(lag)) %>% 
  mutate(lag_nr = paste0('Lag_', trip_nr-1)) %>% 
  select(-date,-trip_nr,-total_trips) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = lag_nr, values_from = lag)
```

This gives the output for result1:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  name  total_trips Trip_1     Trip_2     Trip_3     Trip_4     Trip_5    
  <chr>       <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1 John            4 2017-11-10 2017-12-30 2018-02-18 2019-05-31 NA        
2 Mary            5 2017-04-24 2018-02-18 2018-04-01 2019-03-02 2019-10-18
3 Peter           3 2017-08-02 2019-01-01 2019-12-17 NA         NA        
4 Sue             2 2017-02-03 2019-09-08 NA         NA         NA
```

and result2:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   name [4]
  name  lag_avg     Lag_1    Lag_2    Lag_3    Lag_4   
  <chr> <drtn>      <drtn>   <drtn>   <drtn>   <drtn>  
1 John  189.00 days  50 days  50 days 467 days  NA days
2 Mary  226.75 days 300 days  42 days 335 days 230 days
3 Peter 433.50 days 517 days 350 days  NA days  NA days
4 Sue   947.00 days 947 days  NA days  NA days  NA days
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but how do I fix the error here.                                                       > data <- data %>% 
+   mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')) %>% 
+   arrange(name, date) %>% 
+   group_by(name) %>%
+   mutate(trip_nr = rank(date),
+          total_trips = n()) %>% 
+   ungroup() 
Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: also error in result 2     > View(result1)
> result2 <- data %>% 
+   group_by(name) %>% 
+   mutate(lag = difftime(date, lag(date), units = 'days'),
+          lag_avg = mean(lag, na.rm = T)) %>% 
+   ungroup() %>%
+   filter(!is.na(lag)) %>% 
+   mutate(lag_nr = paste0('Lag_', trip_nr-1)) %>% 
+   select(-date,-trip_nr,-total_trips) %>% 
+   pivot_wider(names_from = lag_nr, values_from = lag)
Error in select(., -date, -trip_nr, -total_trips) : 
  unused arguments (-date, -trip_nr, -total_trips)

Comment: It seems you might have a package conflict (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866178/dplyrn-returns-error-error-n-should-only-be-called-in-a-data-context). This can be solved by making sure dplyr is imported last or by specifying the package explicitely (dplyr::n() instead of just n() ). Same for the second error: try dplyr::select().

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
data$date <- as.character(data$date)
data <- data[order(as.Date(data$date,"%d/%m/%Y")),]
data <- data.table(data)
data[,date := as.Date(date,"%d/%m/%Y")]
#trips
data[,Trips:=seq(.N),by="name"]
#time diff in "days" between trips
data[,Lag:=shift(date,1),by="name"]
data[,diff:=difftime(Lag,date,"days"),by="name"]
data[,diff:=abs(as.numeric(diff))]
#creating second summary table
data_summary_second_table <- data[,.(Avg_lag=mean(diff,na.rm = TRUE)),by="name"]
```