# Dutch sentiment analysis using R

Tags: r, nlp

In RStudio, I have column containing **Dutch** sentences which I would like to add a polarity score between -1.0 and +1.0 to via sentiment analysis. I've already tried to use the `pattern.nlp` package from jwfijffels, but this didn't work for me. I found an instruction on https://github.com/bnosac/pattern.nlp in which it is explained that - in order for the nlp package to work, you should download a specific version of Python and perform some additional steps. However, these steps are a bit vague to me.

Is there someone who can explain this installation process to me in more detail? Actually, the whole section under "Installation" is a bit of a mystery to me. What should I download specifically?
Where to run the code `pip install pattern`? How do I properly set the PATH? It would be much appreciated if someone would guide me trough it step by step.

Or: if someone knows another way to perform sentiment analysis on text, I would of course be open to it, e.g. translating the Dutch sentences to English and then perform the sentiment analysis. Or would such a translation be a bad idea?

Here a set of 6 Dutch sentences.

```
text = c("Slechte bediening, van begin tot eind",
         "Het eten was heerlijk en de bediening was fantastisch",
         "Geweldige service en beleefde bediening",
         "Verschrikkelijk. Ik had een vlieg in mijn soep", 
         "Het was oké. De bediening kon wat beter, maar het eten was wel lekker. Leuk sfeertje wel!",
         "Ondanks dat het druk was toch op tijd ons eten gekregen. Complimenten aan de kok voor het op smaak brengen van mijn biefstuk")
identifier <- c("3", "4", "6", "7", "1", "5")
df <- data.frame(identifier, text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentiment analysis (using a dictionary) is basically just a pattern matching task. I think this becomes clear when using the `tidytext` package and [reading the book about it](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html).

So I wouldn't bother with such a complex setup here. Instead, I would convert the dictionary they are using (which is from [here](https://github.com/clips/pattern)) into a `data.frame` and then use `tidytext`. Unfortunately, the dictionary is stored in XML format and I'm not very familiar with that, so the code looks a little hacky:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(tidytext)

sentiment_nl <- read_xml(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clips/pattern/master/pattern/text/nl/nl-sentiment.xml"
) %>% 
  as_list() %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    tibble::enframe(attributes(x))
  }) %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(str_detect("form", name)))  %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id) %>% 
  mutate(form = tolower(form), # lowercase all words to ignore case during matching
         polarity = as.numeric(polarity),
         subjectivity = as.numeric(subjectivity),
         intensity = as.numeric(intensity),
         confidence = as.numeric(confidence))
```

But the output is correct for the purpose:

```
head(sentiment_nl)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 11
#>      id form  cornetto_id cornetto_synset… wordnet_id pos   sense polarity
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>       <chr>            <chr>      <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 amst… r_a-16677   ""               ""         JJ    van …      0  
#> 2     2 ange… r_a-8929    ""               ""         JJ    Enge…      0.1
#> 3     3 arab… r_a-16693   ""               ""         JJ    van …      0  
#> 4     4 arde… r_a-17252   ""               ""         JJ    van …      0  
#> 5     5 arnh… r_a-16698   ""               ""         JJ    van …      0  
#> 6     6 asse… r_a-16700   ""               ""         JJ    van …      0  
#> # … with 3 more variables: subjectivity <dbl>, intensity <dbl>,
#> #   confidence <dbl>
```

Now we can use the functions from `tidytext` and the broader `tidyverse` to lookup the words in the dictionary and attach the score to each word. `summarise()` is used to get exactly one value per text (that's also why you need the `text_id`).

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("Het eten was heerlijk en de bediening was fantastisch", 
                          "Verschrikkelijk. Ik had een vlieg in mijn soep", 
                          "Het was oké. De bediening kon wat beter, maar het eten was wel lekker. Leuk sfeertje wel!",
                          "Ondanks dat het druk was toch op tijd ons eten gekregen. Complimenten aan de kok voor het op smaak brengen van mijn biefstuk"))

df %>% 
  mutate(text_id = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text, drop = FALSE) %>% 
  inner_join(sentiment_nl, by = c("word" = "form")) %>%
  group_by(text_id) %>% 
  summarise(text = head(text, 1),
            polarity = mean(polarity),
            subjectivity = mean(subjectivity),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   text_id text                                             polarity subjectivity
#>     <int> <chr>                                               <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1       1 Het eten was heerlijk en de bediening was fanta…    0.56         0.72 
#> 2       2 Verschrikkelijk. Ik had een vlieg in mijn soep     -0.5          0.9  
#> 3       3 Het was oké. De bediening kon wat beter, maar h…    0.6          0.98 
#> 4       4 Ondanks dat het druk was toch op tijd ons eten …   -0.233        0.767
```

As I said, more on this (and NLP) is explained on [tidytextmining.com](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html), so don't worry if this looks complicated to you now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The output you're showing looks promising. Only I got the following error: `Error: n() must only be used inside dplyr verbs.` Any idea why and how I can fix it?

Comment: According to [Saurabh Bade in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866178/dplyrn-returns-error-error-n-should-only-be-called-in-a-data-context): "This is because of the conflicts in packages, i.e. summarize/summarise is present in "dplyr" package and in "plyr" package too (in this case which function was called from which package). It can be fixed by changing `mutate`to `dplyr::mutate`, and `summarise` to `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: Yes, totally! I haven't used `plyr` in years as `dplyr` is the successor and is meant to fully replace it. This is why some functions have problems when you load both packages. Of course it's fine to still use `plyr` if you like certain function but I would recommend looking up how you can replace your `plyr` code bit by bit and use `plyr::` to call functions which you still want to use.

Comment: How would I be able to perform the analysis on column level, rather than on the data set as a whole? In other words, how would I be  able to make sure an identifier called `id` is - after the sentiment analysis - still present in the data set? I've updated my question with a new example data set. I tried to change all `text` in the dplyr solution to `df$text` in the hope it would then only perform on the column, but this didn't work. Also, putting in the `id` in the `summarise` of the dplyr solution didn't work

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the line `mutate(text_id = row_number())` I added an id column because you didn't have one and it is necessary for the call to `summarise`. The reason I chose the column name `text_id` was that the dictionary already contains the column `id`, which creates a mess since you can't have two columns with the same name.

Comment: If you want to keep the `id` column you created, simply rename it or rename the one in the dictionary. E.g., with `rename(text_id = id)`.

Comment: I changed the example data once again. It seems that some rows (that contain text) go missing after the sentiment analyis. In the example, the rows with identifier `3` and `6` do not appear in the final `df`, though they contain text

Comment: Hey, just so you know: it is generally considered poor etiquette to keep changing the goal post of a question. If you have follow-up questions, post them as a new question. The reason why 3 and 6 disappear is that they do not contain any words from the dictionary. This might be surprising in the case of "Slechte" in the first text. However , the equivalent in the dictionary is "slecht". You can look into lemmatization (or stemming), fuzzy matching or a better dictionary to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, didn't know this. Appreciate the help

Comment: I don't know about dutch lammatizers but you can use stemming. Just add this to the dictionary: `mutate(stem = textstem::stem_words(form))` and this before the matching: `mutate(stem = textstem::stem_words(word))`. Then matching using the stem.

Comment: Just saw you posted a [new question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220706/missing-rows-after-sentiment-analysis-using-dplyr-in-r/64223449#64223449). You've got a full answer there :)