# Missing rows after sentiment analysis using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

When doing a sentiment analysis in R using `dplyr` that has been described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119521/dutch-sentiment-analysis-using-r), it appears that some of my rows go missing. I've provided a set of 6 Dutch sentences. As can be seen, row `3` and `6` do not appear in the new `df` that includes the sentiment analysis.

I tried to change the `"drop"` to `"keep"`, `"drop"` and `"NULL"`. I also tried to hashtag certain parts after the `df %>%` solution, but both without result.

Is someone able to explain this behavior to me? And how can I fix it?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(tidytext)

#Example data set
text = c("Slechte bediening, van begin tot eind",
         "Het eten was heerlijk en de bediening was fantastisch",
         "Geweldige service en beleefde bediening",
         "Verschrikkelijk. Ik had een vlieg in mijn soep", 
         "Het was oké. De bediening kon wat beter, maar het eten was wel lekker. Leuk sfeertje wel!",
         "Ondanks dat het druk was toch op tijd ons eten gekregen. Complimenten aan de kok voor het op smaak brengen van mijn biefstuk")
identifier <- c("3", "4", "6", "7", "1", "5")
df <- data.frame(identifier, text)

#Sentiment analysis Dutch
sentiment_nl <- read_xml(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clips/pattern/master/pattern/text/nl/nl-sentiment.xml"
) %>% 
  as_list() %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    tibble::enframe(attributes(x))
  }) %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(str_detect("form", name)))  %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id) %>% 
  mutate(polarity = as.numeric(polarity),
         subjectivity = as.numeric(subjectivity),
         intensity = as.numeric(intensity),
         confidence = as.numeric(confidence))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(identifier = identifier) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text, drop = FALSE) %>% 
  inner_join(sentiment_nl, by = c("word" = "form")) %>%
  group_by(identifier) %>% 
  summarise(text = head(text, 1),
            polarity = mean(polarity),
            subjectivity = mean(subjectivity),
            .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: If you change your `inner_join` to a `left_join` you can see what's going on: sentence 3 and 6 do not have any words that are in `sentiment_nl`. I think you need to apply [stemming](https://smltar.com/stemming.html#how-to-stem-text-in-r), since e.g. sentence 3 contains the word 'slechte', but `sentiment_nl` only contains 'slecht'.

Comment: Thanks! How would I be able to implement `wordStem(text, language = "nl")` in the proposed solution? I can't seem to find a way to integrate it into the `dplyr` solution, nor to perform stemming as preprocessing step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in @Bas comment, some word forms are missing from the dictionary. You can solve this by getting a better dictionary, stemming or lemmatization.

Ideally, you would use a lemmatizer, which is superior to stemming. However, I think in the example you've given a stemmer is working fine. So you can use this to construct the dictionary:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(tidytext)
library(textstem)

sentiment_nl <- read_xml(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clips/pattern/master/pattern/text/nl/nl-sentiment.xml"
) %>% 
  as_list() %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    tibble::enframe(attributes(x))
  }) %>% 
  mutate(id = cumsum(str_detect("form", name)))  %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id) %>% 
  mutate(form = tolower(form),
         stem = textstem::stem_words(form), # this is the new line
         polarity = as.numeric(polarity),
         subjectivity = as.numeric(subjectivity),
         intensity = as.numeric(intensity),
         confidence = as.numeric(confidence))
```

And then also stem the words in the text before matching on the stems:

```
df %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text, drop = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(stem = textstem::stem_words(word)) %>% 
  inner_join(sentiment_nl, by = "stem") %>%
  group_by(identifier) %>% 
  summarise(text = head(text, 1),
            polarity = mean(polarity),
            subjectivity = mean(subjectivity),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   identifier text                                          polarity subjectivity
#>   <chr>      <chr>                                            <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 1          Het was oké. De bediening kon wat beter, maa…    0.6          0.98 
#> 2 3          Slechte bediening, van begin tot eind           -0.7          0.9  
#> 3 4          Het eten was heerlijk en de bediening was fa…    0.56         0.72 
#> 4 5          Ondanks dat het druk was toch op tijd ons et…   -0.233        0.767
#> 5 6          Geweldige service en beleefde bediening          0.7          0.95 
#> 6 7          Verschrikkelijk. Ik had een vlieg in mijn so…   -0.3          0.733
```